# Running python files with Matplotlib in console

Tags: python, powershell, matplotlib

Normally when I wish to execute a python file  I would change my directory in powershell and use the command,

```
python -i filename.py
```

I am currently using the library matplotlib for several scripts. Ive successfully launched them within Pycharm, however i also want to be able to run them within powershell or another console, unfortunately it is having troubles importing. Is there anything i can do?

Comment: What specifically is failing to import?  I've used matplotlib running from the console (it opens a new window with matplotlib.pyplot.show).

Comment: @garlon4 ImportError: essentially anything i try to import, even import matplotlib.pyplot as plt will give me "ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams'" in console

Comment: Usually, that error is because you have a local module with the same name as a standard library module.  matplotlib is trying to import the standard library module, but getting the local one.  Can you paste the entire error that you get?  It should show which local file is causing the problem.

Comment: @garlon4 yes that was exactly it, i had a file named dis.py that was interfering, thank you i otherwise would not have looked into that!